# How to connect from proxy server using php and java?

Tags: java, php, proxy

I have to connect to internet through proxy server using php and java.....

As we have to use internet connection in my project in various files.

There is any way to write program for connect through proxy server in a common file and we can call that file wherever we wants?

For both php and java..

Can any one help me?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at. Do you want your java/php programs to connect to an internet server through a proxy?

Comment: In my project i am using php as front end and java as a back end ... And both java and php code needs to connect to internet , So i need individual code for php and as well as java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is your friend!

PHP
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php#92586

```
$opts = array('http' => array('proxy' => 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8080', 'request_fulluri' => true));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.php.net', false, $context);
echo $data;
```

JAVA
http://jaydeepm.wordpress.com/2009/08/08/url-connection-via-proxy-the-java-1-5-way/

```
String proxyHost = "proxy.xyz.co.in"; //replace with your proxy server name or IP
int proxyPort = 8080; //your proxy server port
SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort);
Proxy httpProxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);

URLConnection urlConn = null;
BufferedReader reader = null;
String response = "";
String output = "";
URL url = new URL("www.google.com");
//Pass the Proxy instance defined above, to the openConnection() method
urlConn = url.openConnection(httpProxy); 
urlConn.connect();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
response = reader.readLine();
while (response!=null) {
    output+= response;
    response = reader.readLine();
}   
System.out.println("Output: " + output);
```